# Get distinct records of two columns in a join with 6 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join, distinct

I have two MySQL tables SPONSORSHIPS and EVENTS. I want to display a list of SPONSORSHIPS sorted by the category of the events they sponsor, but to only show a sponsorship once under each event. Sample join table:

```
SPONSORSHIPS
sponsorhipid | sponsorid | eventid | date       | 
-------------|-----------|---------|------------|
1            | 3         |  20     | 06/01/2013 |
2            | 2         |  20     | 06/02/2013 |
3            | 3         |  20     | 06/03/2013 |
4            | 2         |  21     | 06/04/2013 |

EVENTS
eventid | name      | premium    | 
--------|-----------|------------|
20      | Lunch     | 0          | 
21      | Dinner    | 1          |
```

What I'd like to have as a result of the JOIN is:

```
sponsorhipid | sponsorid | eventid | date       | name    | premium  | 
-------------|-----------|---------|------------|---------| ---------|
1            | 3         |  20     | 06/01/2013 | Lunch   | 0        |
2            | 2         |  20     | 06/02/2013 | Lunch   | 0        |
4            | 2         |  21     | 06/04/2013 | Dinner  | 1        |
```

I tried `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` but these collapse the events so if sponsor #2 sponsors two different events they'd still be shown only once. How can I achieve this? Here is my last SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (sponsorships.sponsorshipid), sponsorships.*, events.*
            FROM events 
            INNER JOIN sponsorships
            ON events.eventid = sponsorships.eventid
```

Thanks so much for any pointers!

Comment: How can the same sponsor sponsor the same event twice? That makes no sense. The PK on the first table should be (sponsor_id,event_id). Oh, and your dates are really yyyy-mm-dd, right?

Comment: @Strawberry the candidate key is clearly {sponsor_id, event_id, date} since you can apparently sponsor lunch on more than one day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use nested sub-queries like this:

```
SELECT s.sponsorhipid, s.sponsorid, s.eventid, s.date
       ,e.name, e.premium
FROM EVENTS e 
JOIN
(
    SELECT s1.* FROM SPONSORSHIPS s1
    JOIN
    (
      SELECT sponsorid, MIN(Date) As minDate
      FROM SPONSORSHIPS
      GROUP BY eventid,sponsorid
    ) s2
    ON s1.sponsorid = s2.sponsorid
    AND s1.date = s2.minDate
) s
ON e.eventid = s.eventid;
```

Output:

```
| SPONSORHIPID | SPONSORID | EVENTID |       DATE |   NAME | PREMIUM |
|--------------|-----------|---------|------------|--------|---------|
|            1 |         3 |      20 | 06/01/2013 |  Lunch |       0 |
|            2 |         2 |      20 | 06/02/2013 |  Lunch |       0 |
|            4 |         2 |      21 | 06/04/2013 | Dinner |       1 |
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d206a0/7)

Comment: @ConradFrix - Ahh. Actually first I used `MAX()` but OP is looking for min date so updated the function but not the alias. Thanks for correcting.